# Quelle est la différence entre "fété" et "fête"?

Tags: vocabulaire

I have seen the usage of both "fété" and "fête" for the word "party" in english and I was wondering if there was any difference between the two?

Merci!

Comment: Je n'ai jamais lu le mot "fété" (en partant du principe que ce n'est pas le mot "fêté"). Quel est le contexte? Quel pays?

Comment: @Exocytosis
Je pense que je me suis peut-être confondu. Pardon !

Comment: What do you mean? What mistake did you make? The spelling of "fêté" or something else?

Comment: @Exocytosis I think I mistook "fêté" to be "fété" instead, like the answer by Dimitris has pointed out

Comment: Thinking about it, you MAY have read "fété". Young French simplify the language and do not respect all rules at all.

Answer (score 4):

No native speaker but I think fété does not exist. The corrected form is fête. The corresponding verb is fêter whose past participle is fêté. May be it is the last one that you have seen.

Answer (score 1):

Like Dimitris said "fête" could mean anything like holiday, party, celebration that you could relate to "festival" or "feast" in English, as for "fété", it is the past participle (participe passé) of the verb "fêter" which basically means celebrate or observe e.g: Hier, il a fêté son anniversaire (he celebrated his birthday yesterday) or les Chrétiens fètent Noël (Christians celebrate or observe Christmas).